# Duplicate associations in Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am using fixtures to load test data on a Ruby on Rails project. I moved to Factory Girl, but I am getting duplicate entries for associations.

I have a `Group` model and a `Value` model. A `Group` can have multiple `Values`.

Also, I am using Cucumber for my tests. And `FactoryGirl.lint` to populate the database.

#### My fixtures

groups.yml

```
group_1:
  name: "Flavour"
```

values.yml

```
value_1:
  name: "Strawberry"
  group: group_1

value_2:
  name: "Mint"
  group: group_1

value_3:
  name: "Chocolate"
  group: group_1
```

This works just fine. A single `Group` is created and the 3 `Values` are attached to it.

#### My factories

groups.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group do
    name "Flavour"
  end
end
```

values.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :value_1, class: :value do
    name "Strawberry"
    group
  end

  factory :value_2, class: :value do
    name "Mint"
    group
  end

  factory :value_3, class: :value do
    name "Chocolate"
    group
  end
end
```

This is not working. Factory Girl is creating 3 `Groups`, each one associated to 1 `Value`.

Is this normal behaviour for Factory Girl?

Also, I read that `use_transactional_fixtures` should be set to true. This is already the case.

Comment: FactoryGirl is usually more relevant when you try to create random relevant objects and not specific one. In your case I would advise plain old ActiveRecord creation : `g = Group.create(name: 'Flavour') ; %w(Strawberry Mint Chocolate).each {|n| Value.create(name: n, group_id: g.id)`}.

Comment: You can always overwrite an attribute with factory girl : `FactoryGirl.create :value_1, group: a_group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you really have grasped the conceptual differences between using fixtures and factories.

- With fixtures you have these static object definitions that get chucked into the database on each test run. Its like your database has a "zero" state with a bunch of data already. Feels nice, warm and fuzzy (Oh I don't have to set everything up, so nice!) but its a horrible idea in reality since it masks any errors caused by an empty table!
- With factories you define objects dynamically instead and create them when needed. You use a tool like [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) to clean out any residual state between tests. You start each test with nothing.

`FactoryGirl.lint` does not populate the database. Its a linter that checks that your factory definitions are correct.

There is absolutely zero point in using factory_girl if you just create a bunch of fixtures with it. So instead you want to do something like:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :value do
    name { ["Strawberry", "Mint", "Chocolate"].sample }
    group
  end
end
```

One of the mental hurdles of going from fixtures to factories is you have to stop writing tests like if you where using fixture data:

```
describe "GET /users/:id" do

  let!(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:json) { JSON.parse(response.body) }

  before { get users_path(@user), format: :json }

  it "has the correct name" do
    # bad
    expect(json["name"]).to eq "John Doe" # strong coupling to factory!

    # good 
    expect(json["name"]).to eq user.name # we don't know what the factory generates.
  end
end
```

If you have to have a test where a certain factory value must be known or if a factory needs to be associated to a certain object then do it explicitly instead of making a mess of your definitions.

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, name: 'Max') }
let(:item) { user.items.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:item)) }

it "has an awesome name" do
  expect(user.name).to eq 'Max'
end

it "is associated" do
  expect(item.user).to eq user
end
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out. I'm taking note of what you explained and will implement it properly down the line.

Answer (score 2):

Your value factories are told to use the group factory for their group, and the group factory is told to make a new group with name 'Flavor'.  What you want to do differently is that you want the group factory to return the existing 'Flavor' rather than a new one.   Here is how to do that.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :group, class: :group do
    name 'Flavor'
    initialize_with {Group.find_or_initialize_by(name: name)}
  end
end
```

That is saying if you already have a group with desired name, use existing group.  Written as above so that there is a default name, and you get the same 'use existing if present' behavior when passing in an alternate name.

Comment: What others note about differences between factories and fixtures is valid.  But there are test situations where the technique above is required.

Comment: Thanks for the input @elc. I will use that for now, and implement max's suggestion down the line.